# Fail to currying F# printf function

Tags: f#

I was trying to do the following:

```
let print = printf "%A"
print "Test"
print [1..10]
```

I got an error says the `print` function is expecting a string thus doesn't take `[1..10]`. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Oh I didn't find that one first. Thanks for pointing out!